# Getting the values of checkbox in new activity android

Tags: android-activity

I need a little bit help regarding retrieval of values which are selected or ticked in the Checkbox list. Once the user clicks on confirm button, the selected items must appear in new activity.
I'm very basic to android, so needs a little assistance.

***FoodMainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.sailalith.sample1;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FoodMainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] city= {
        "Indian bread : Rumali roti -   Rs.  20",
        "plain naan                 -   Rs.  15",
        "Paneer Butter Masala       -   Rs. 120",
        "Mushroom Curry             -   Rs. 100",
        "Jeera rice                 -   Rs. 120",
        "Egg Masala                 -   Rs.  80",
        "Green peas masala          -   Rs.  60",
        "Veg. Biryani               -   Rs. 120",
        "Dal fry                    -   Rs.  90",
        "Malai Koftha curry         -   Rs. 120",
        "Veg. Fried rice            -   Rs.  80",
        "Veg. Pulav                 -   Rs.  70",
        "   "
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_main);

    // -- Display mode of the ListView
    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });

    ListView listview= getListView();
    //  listview.setChoiceMode(listview.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    //  listview.setChoiceMode(listview.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listview.setChoiceMode(listview.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    //--    text filtering
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,city));
}


public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
    CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) v;
    Toast.makeText(this, city[position] + " checked : " +
            item.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   } 
}
```

***XML file***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
</ListView>

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/testbutton"
    android:text="Confirm"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onListItemClick()` function, you are getting position of the selected option in the listview. You can retrieve the selected item using `position`.

Just add this line in `onListItemClick()` function :

```
String str = listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Comment: thanks bro..how can retrieve this value to my new activity